# Doing polymorphic model, what's the best approach?

Tags: django, django-models, jsonfield

I'm trying to upscale a project that originally was used by an area to assign reports to their respective departments.
Those reports I want them to be tasks, to broaden the spectrum of use to all of the organization.

Originally, I was using separate models for reports, updates, report files, update files. (Those tables, had almost the same fields)

Now, I'm trying to have a polymorphic model, as shown below:

```
#### TASK TYPE (TASK, UPDATE) 
class TipoTarea(models.Model): 
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre    

###### TASK CATEGORY (TOPIC AND THE AREA WHO IS BEING DIRECTED TO)
class CategoriaTarea(models.Model): 
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    area = models.ForeignKey(Area, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tiempo_atencion = models.IntegerField(default=2)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

##### TASK STATE (CREATED, IN PROCESS, COMPLETED, REASIGNED)
##### REASIGNED STATE, CREATES A NEW TASK WITH A DIFFERENT CATEGORY
class EstadoTarea(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre

###### TASK
###### TASK PARENT WOULD BE USED FOR UPDATES, BUT HOW CAN REASIGNMENTS BE CLASSIFIED
class Tarea(models.Model):
    tipo = models.ForeignKey(TipoTarea, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name = 'tarea') 
    categoria = models.ForeignKey(CategoriaTarea, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name = 'tarea')
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    fecha = models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
    estado = models.ForeignKey(EstadoTarea, default= 1, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    creado_por = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='creador')
    creado = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="actualizaciones", null=True, blank=True)
    modificado = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    modificado_por = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True, null=True, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='modificador')
    extras = models.JSONField(null=True)
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ["fecha"]

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        user = get_current_user()
        if user and not user.pk:
            user = None
        if not self.pk:
            self.creado_por = user
        else:
            self.modificado_por = user
        super(Tarea, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

###### TASK FILES SHOULD I USE THE EXTRAS FIELD (JSONFIELD) IN TASKS MODEL TO STORE THE PATH TO THE FILES?
class ArchivoTarea(models.Model):
    tarea = models.ForeignKey(Tarea, on_delete=models.CASCADE)       
    archivo = models.FileField(upload_to=upload_reporte_file_to)
```

Now, my questions are:

1. Is this the best approach? or am I just complicating things?
2. I'm trying to use a jsonfield, to store differentiation parameters, but I'm having trouble formatting the keys I want to store.
3. Where should I store the files path, in a separate table or in the json field? (Each task or update, should have maximum 5 files.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say `TipoTarea` and `EstadoTarea` should just be Charfields with defined `choices` on your main `Tarea` model. With those foreign keys you'll have to do an unnecessary join every time you query a task on both those tables just to get its state and type, and the interface is worse: `tarea.tipo.nombre` isn't fun to just check what type your task is.

The `CategoriaTarea` is debatable, not sure what it's supposed to represent really, mix of location and time? If you're going to add more to it why not.

The `ArchivoTarea` is good. I'm not sure what you mean by "path to the file". If you need 5 files related to a `Tarea` instance you just create 5 `ArchivoTarea` instances, one for each file which you save using the `archivo` FileField, all of them pointing to the same task. If you somehow want the filename store separately you can add a `filename` Charfield to the `ArchivoTarea` model. (e.g with `t` being a `Tarea` instance: `t.archivotarea_set.values_list('filename', flat=True)` gives you all filenames for `t`)

JsonFields don't really require formatting although it helps to keep the same structure of keys/values t across all your model's instances. Django will serialize and deserialize from and to python types it for you when saving/reading from the database. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#jsonfield

Comment: Took your advice and changed TipoTarea and EstadoTarea to Charfields.
Categoría, is a growing catalog, so it would be better as it is.

As for the files, I was in doubt, if there was a more practical way to store them, like for example storing them as json in the same table as Tarea, but reading your input, I think that would complicate things. Thanks a lot!